# Change the scale of a gameObject that is not instantiated in a script in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite, scale, gameobject

In an empty scene i add an empty gameObject and call it "script". I attach a C# script that creates a texture object and put a sprite renderer on that. A webcam image is rendered. I want to change the scale with which the sprite is displayed. This change is already possible manually through the inspector->transform->scale of the script gameObject. However, I want to change only one parameter and hence i need to add a public parameter into the script. How do i - from the script - access the tansform scale of the empty script eventhough there is no such gameObject instantiated within the script?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[RequireComponent(typeof(SpriteRenderer))]
public class contours : MonoBehaviour
{

    SpriteRenderer rend;
    void Start()
    {
        tex = new Texture2D(432, 240, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);
        rend = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        pixel32 = tex.GetPixels32();        
        //get a customized texture here
        tex.SetPixels32(pixel32);
        tex.Apply();

        //create a sprite from that texture
        Sprite newSprite = Sprite.Create(tex, new Rect(0, 0,432,240), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), 100F, 0, SpriteMeshType.FullRect);

        rend.sprite = newSprite;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're asking. If a gameobject is not instantiated, then you can't change the scale of it, cuz the gameobject doesn't exist. Your C# code that instantiates the `Texture` (game?)object will have a reference to the object. Presumably you can call `GetComponent` on it to get the Transform component and adjust the scale with some code

Comment: I agree.. this leads to the question which object do i manipulate when manually changing values in the inspector of the script object? does it change the texture ?

Comment: It's hard for me to answer this cuz I can't see your inspector window (or your gameobjects) (or the code that spawns new gameobjects)

Comment: ok i added the code skeleton and an image of the spectator

Comment: You should be able to get a reference to the transform component from anywhere inside your contours monobehaviour with `GetComponent<Transform>();`. Then you can use `referenceToTransform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 0, 1);` to update the X/Y/Z values with code. ASSUMING the contours monobehaviour exists on that "Script" object I see in your hierarchy

Comment: yes it exists in "Script". that would be `referenceToTransform = GetComponent<Transform>();` in the Start() section and `referenceToTransform.localScale = new Vector3(3.0f,3.0f,1.0f);` in the update section.

Comment: Yes, that should work. But keep in mind that you don't need to update `localScale` every frame if the scale will be the same every time, so you can move the `reference.localScale = whatever` into your `Start()` method too, at least for this specific case

Comment: yep. i want to be able to change the scale during playmode though

Comment: i think there shall be a  `Transform referenceToTransform;` required before start()

Comment: PERFECT IT WORKS also when updating the scales from Update() !!! I didnt know about referencing to the components of an gameObject in the scene so you have been a great help byxor !!! please post an answer so i can close

Comment: Damn, I should have posted this as an answer but I'm too lazy lol. Enjoy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference to the `Transform` component of the very same `GameObject` a component is attached to is a built-in property [`transform`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-transform.html)!
In general you could e.g. do

```
rend.transform.localScale = newLocalScale;
```

However, in your case your own script is attached to the same GameObject as well so all you need to do is

```
transform.localScale = newLocalScale;
```

---

Btw there is also no need whatsoever to create a new `Sprite` instance **every frame**! Altering the texture will automatically also update the `Sprite` based on that texture!

And even then still questionable why you would change all the pixels of a texture every frame ..

Comment: true that. both worked ! perfect ! i got a camera livestream that gets processed on arrival by an opencv library which i then display with the texture object.